# Deletion of kafka logs using retention time

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, spring-kafka

I am working on windows platform, a tool in which i will produce messages to kafka from spring boot application very often(A function will produces message continuously). And i will consumes the messages from node.js application. So the application creates so many topics in a day, kafka logs is occupying full disk space within a week. So i tried with **log.retention.hours** function to delete the logs but i am getting **Error while deleting segments**, **java.nio.file.FileSystemException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process**.

NOTE: I haven't get a solution to fix it, i don't know the reason why it is happening. I have two questions

1) Do i need to configure any thing in my application or do i need to send confirmation to kafka server from my spring boot application that i finished producing messages to the topic so that kafka will delete it.

2) how can i connect to kafka server from other machines?(i am hosting kafka, zookeeper in a machine and i am producing messages to a topic from the same machine. now i am trying to consumes messages from other machine but i couldn't connect to the kafka server)

Below are the configuration i am using in the spring boot application and i will produce messages to topics.

```java
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) No, you shouldn't configure anything more than retention time. You shouldn't also stop the producers, or consumers for this.Anyway, other factors may affect for retention to kick in (f.e: being in an open log segment,..) 2) You should configure an "advertised listener" for your clients from outside to be able to connect (and the bootstrap property from your clients must point to that)

Comment: This same "used by another process" error is posted continuously... The short answer is that Kafka is not tested on Windows machines, and Windows handles file differently than Linux. Plus it is not encouraged to run on Windows (although it can) outside of testing environments, but even then, Docker might work better.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri if many clients are there, should i need to configure for all clients?

Comment: @cricket_007 so kafka wont support for windows platform? why windows is not allowing to delete kafka logs

Comment: The Apache test servers are all running Linux, and Confluent Enterprise customers mostly run on Linux as well. The Windows support is mostly community driven, and the Java API methods around file-handles is more strict about holding onto data than the Unix Filessytem is